# Retrieving Native Connection from JBOSS wrapped Connection

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, jdbctemplate

I need to pass an array Object to Oracle 11 DB. I am using annotations based `Spring 3.1` and using `SimpleJdbcCall` to call the procedure on JBOSS server. Here is the relevant `jdbcCall`.

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                              .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                              .withProcedureName(IbeginDataBaseConstants.PROCEDURE_CREATE_NEW_ADMIN.VAL)
                              .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("inUserEmpID", OracleTypes.INTEGER))
                              .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("inCountryIDs", OracleTypes.ARRAY, "ibo_number_array" ))
                              .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("inSysRoleID", OracleTypes.INTEGER))
                              .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("inLoggedIn", OracleTypes.INTEGER))
                              .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("outStatus", OracleTypes.CHAR))
                              .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("outMsg", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));
```

As you can see `inCountryIDs`is an array that I need to send.

**With help from google, I was able to get multiple ways through which I can send Array to DB. Here is the first one.**

```
SqlTypeValue value = new AbstractSqlTypeValue() {
      protected Object createTypeValue(Connection conn, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = new ArrayDescriptor(typeName, conn);
        ARRAY idArray = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn, ids);
        return idArray;
      }
```

And I added it to parameter source using

```
            sourceMap.addValue("inUserEmpID", newAdmin.getEmpId());
    sourceMap.addValue("inCountryIDs", value);

    sourceMap.addValue("inSysRoleID", newAdmin.getRoleId());
    sourceMap.addValue("inLoggedIn", newAdmin.getLoggedInId());
```

And the Exception that I got was 
`org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection`

I understood the reason, SqlTypeValue implemention requires a OracleConnection whereas Spring passes WrappedConnection.

So, I tried to unwrap the connection using `WrappedConnection` class with this code.

```
WrappedConnection wrappedConnection = conn.unwrap(WrappedConnection.class);
```

But here the exception was

```
Not a wrapper for: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection
```

In another try, I tried to cast existing connection to WrappedConnection using explicit cast with this.

```
WrappedConnection wrappedConn = (WrappedConnection)conn;
```

And still no luck.
Exception.

```
org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection
```

Well, All I had to do is to retrieve the underlying connection, so I tried to cast it into `WrappedConnectionJDK6` so that I would be able to call the relevent method there.

```
WrappedConnectionJDK6 wrappedConnection = (WrappedConnectionJDK6)conn;
```

leads to 
    org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6 cannot be cast to org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6

**And the second approach**

```
Map in = Collections.singletonMap("inCountryIDs", new SqlArrayValue(idsArray));
```

The problem with this approach is that `Collections.singletonMap` returns an immutable map. So, I can't use it to add more parameters.

Is there any way through which I can retrieve the underlying connection in JBoss Wrapped Connection ? Or is there any other mechanism through which I can pass an array paramter without having to interact with connection ?